# Create a mysql trigger to insert data when a column updated

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_2` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `itm_master`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.transfer_status='YES' THEN
        INSERT into activity_tbl (`evnt_date`,`con_type`,`username`,`item_serial`,`item_model`,`item_type`,`to_status`)
        VALUES (now(),'Update',NEW.user,NEW.item_serial,NEW.master_item_model,NEW.master_item_type,NEW.item_status);
    END IF;
END
```

I'd like to create a trigger to insert data into activity_tbl whenever the transfer_status field updated in item_master table. I use this query but i am receiving Mysql Error

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_2` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `itm_master`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.transfer_status='YES' THEN
        INSERT into activity_tbl (`evnt_date`,`con_type`,`username`,`item_serial`,`item_model`,`item_type`,`to_status`)
        VALUES (now(),'Update',NEW.user,NEW.item_serial,NEW.master_item_model,NEW.master_item_type,NEW.item_status);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> ## 1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '' Ã  la ligne 7

Comment: Personally I try to avoid triggers, when you look at the code it will seem like magic that this data is added.  It's more readable to insert the data when the other data is inserted.  Besides that I cant read that error message...

Comment: I agree with that one

Comment: Which is your code, the first block or the second? I can see that the 2nd would have a syntax error as it's incomplete (no END IF, no END for the BEGIN). Is that what the error says in English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work. I am out of creative commentary at the moment.

SCHEMA:

```
create table itm_master
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    transfer_status VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    user VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    item_serial VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    master_item_model VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    master_item_type VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    item_status VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
create table activity_tbl
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    `evnt_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `con_type` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `item_serial` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `item_model` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `item_type` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `to_status` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

TRIGGER:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_2;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `update_2` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `itm_master`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.transfer_status='YES' THEN
        INSERT into activity_tbl (`evnt_date`,`con_type`,`username`,`item_serial`,`item_model`,`item_type`,`to_status`)
        VALUES (now(),'Update',NEW.user,NEW.item_serial,NEW.master_item_model,NEW.master_item_type,NEW.item_status);
    END IF;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Test:

```
INSERT itm_master(transfer_status, user, item_serial, master_item_model, master_item_type, item_status) values
('a','b','c','d','e','f');

UPDATE itm_master SET transfer_status='blah' WHERE id=1;
select * from activity_tbl;
-- no rows

UPDATE itm_master SET transfer_status='YES' WHERE id=1;
select * from activity_tbl;
+----+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | evnt_date           | con_type | username | item_serial | item_model | item_type | to_status |
+----+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | 2016-09-13 00:14:26 | Update   | b        | c           | d          | e         | f         |
+----+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

The `DELIMITER` wrapper is not needed for PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: I used a trigger once to delete on cascade, because I had full text index and Mysql 5.4...

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked.
Although i found the reason for the error....
my version of mysql doesn't support multiple triggers with the same function.